# Owl Carousel 2 - не изменяется размер owl-stage

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

Такая проблема:
Я подключил Owl-Carousel успешно на сайт. Он у меня установлен во весь экран компьютера (w:100%; h:100%), но когда я открываю боковое меню и меняю ширину owl, то размер `.owl-stage` и `.owl-item` остается неизменным, потому что там фиксированная ширина (в пикселях).

Заметил, что ширина фиксированная меняется при открытии инспектора кода или при изменении ширины экрана браузера -> т.е. идет перерасчет ширины.

`autowidth:true` не помогает(

Надо какой-то `рефрешер` в js, но который не перезагружал страницу целиком, а просто заставлял Owl перерасчитать ширину

---

**UPD**: нашел в интернете примерное решение - использовать `refresh.owl.carousel`

написал код, но срабатывает он со 2 клика:

```
$('.menu_hamburger').click(function(){
    owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
});
```

---

Изначально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После открытия меню:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После открытия инспектора страницы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После закрытия меню:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А разве данное боковое меню у вас не fixed или absolute?

Comment: Забыл описать, боковое меню fixed, но при открытии меню, owl-carousel меняет ширину с 100% на 80:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью `refresh.owl.carousel`. Это костыль, но хоть как-то работает.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var $owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        // autoWidth:true,
        loop:true,
        dots: false,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:10000
        // autoHeight:true
    });

    $('.menu_hamburger').click(function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
        }, 390); //390 - это время закрытия/открытия бокового меню
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Не глядя конкретно на живом сайте могу предложить разве что костыль. Повесить на закрытие меню вот это

```
$('.menu_hamburger').click(function () { 
    $('.owl-item').css('width',$(document).width()); 
    $('.owl-stage').css('width',$(document).width() * $('.owl-item').length); 
});
```

Comment: Сейчас проверим. Я с js на вы, поэтому я понимаю, что легко.

Comment: Не помогло(( `$('.menu_hamburger').click(function () {
        console.log("works");
        $('.owl-item').css('width',$(document).width());
    });`

Comment: width у owl-item в инспекторе не меняется?

Comment: Да, но там фишка еще в том, что надо менять `width` и `translate3d` у .owl-stage. Может есть какая-то иммитация изменения размера экрана на ноль? Тогда owl сам пересчитает ширину

Comment: да - меняется, или да - не меняется? owl-stage (как я понимаю это суммарная ширина всех слайдов) тоже можно поменять (в ответе привел код как это сделать). А что касается translate3d, то там на скрине не видно полностью че он из себя представляет.

Comment: Окей, я тогда сейчас код скину. Просто там более 200 строк кода)